# Trouble Calculating Early and Late Times, Total Slack, and Identifying Critical Path in Python for a Project Management Problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix, data-science

To find the critical path for the following project given in the `project_table`, you need to calculate early and late times as well as the Total Slack (MT) for each task in the project.

```py
# This is the project table provided as data

project_table = [
['TASK', 'DURATION',  'PREDECESSORS'],
[   'a',          3,              []],
[   'b',          5,              []],
[   'c',          4,              []],
[   'd',          1,           ['a']],
[   'e',          5,           ['a']],
[   'f',          2,      ['b', 'd']],
[   'g',          4,      ['b', 'd']],
[   'h',          3,           ['c']],
[   'i',          5,      ['g', 'h']],
[   'j',          4,           ['e']], 
[   'k',          2, ['f', 'h', 'i']],
[   'l',          6,           ['e']],
[   'm',          3,      ['g', 'h']]
]
```

, and from the previous table given as an example we will have to calculate the following:

- ti would be the early start time of the task
- tf would be the early finish time of the task
- Ti would be the late start time of the task
- Tf would be the late finish time of the task
- d would be the duration of the task
- MT would be the Total Slack of the task, which is calculated using this equation for each task (i.e., for each row):

MT = Tf - ti - d

Rows of tasks with an empty `'PREDECESSORS'` column mean that they have no predecessors.

This is the "generic structure" (excluding the task rows) of the table to be presented, with the column headers the table should have:

```py
table_with_times_and_mt = [
['TASK', 'DURATION', 'ti', 'tf', 'Ti', 'Tf', 'MT']
]
```

Next, you should fill in the task and duration columns with the data from `project_table`.

```py
table_with_times_and_mt = [
['TASK', 'DURATION', 'ti', 'tf', 'Ti', 'Tf', 'MT'],
[   'a',          3,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ],
[   'b',          5,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ],
[   'c',          4,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ],
[   'd',          1,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ],
[   'e',          5,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ],
[   'f',          2,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ],
[   'g',          4,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ],
[   'h',          3,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ],
[   'i',          5,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ],
[   'j',          4,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ],
[   'k',          2,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ],
[   'l',          6,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ],
[   'm',          3,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ]
]
```

Then, calculate the values of `ti`, `tf`, `Ti`, and `Tf` for each task, and using the MT formula, calculate it for each task. Fill in the data to obtain the following table.

Finally, print the resulting list of lists as a table or matrix.

```py
for row in table_with_times_and_mt:  print(row)
```

So it should look like this:

```py
table_with_times_and_mt = [
['TASK', 'DURATION', 'ti', 'tf', 'Ti', 'Tf', 'MT'],
[   'a',          3,    0,    3,    0,    4,    1],
[   'b',          5,    0,    5,    0,    5,    0],
[   'c',          4,    0,    5,    0,    6,    2],
[   'd',          1,    3,    4,    4,    5,    1],
[   'e',          5,    3,    8,    4,   10,    2],
[   'f',          2,    5,   14,    5,   14,    7],
[   'g',          4,    5,    9,    5,    9,    0],
[   'h',          3,    4,    9,    6,    9,    2],
[   'i',          5,    9,   14,    9,   14,    0],
[   'j',          4,    8,   14,   10,   14,    2],
[   'k',          2,   14,   16,   14,   16,    0],
[   'l',          6,    8,   16,   10,   16,    2],
[   'm',          3,    9,   16,    9,   16,    4]
]
```

Then, print in the console a list of tasks on the critical path, meaning a list of tasks with an MT of 0 in their column in the `table_with_times_and_mt` table.

In this case, it would be:

```py
critical_path_task_list = ['b', 'g', 'i', 'k']
```

This is my code but it doesn't work well because it has problems not correctly recognizing task precedences, so it can't calculate early and late times:

```py
# Create the table with headers
table_with_times_and_mt = [['TASK', 'DURATION', 'ti', 'tf', 'Ti', 'Tf', 'MT']]

# Initialize the precedence dictionary
precedences = {}

# Calculate early start (ti) and finish times (tf)
for task in project_table:
    task_name, duration, predecessors = task[0], task[1], task[2]
    ti = 0
    for p in predecessors:
        if p in precedences:
            ti = max(ti, precedences[p]['tf'])
        else:
            print(f"Error: Task {task_name} has a non-existent predecessor: {p}")
    tf = ti + duration
    precedences[task_name] = {'ti': ti, 'tf': tf}

# Calculate late start (Ti) and MT
for task in reversed(project_table):
    task_name, duration, predecessors = task[0], task[1], task[2]
    Ti = float('inf')
    for successor in predecessors:
        Ti = min(Ti, precedences[successor]['ti'])
    Ti -= duration
    Tf = precedences[task_name]['tf']
    MT = Tf - Ti - duration
    task.append(Ti)
    task.append(Tf)
    task.append(MT)
    table_with_times_and_mt.append(task)
```

```py
# Print the table
for row in table_with_times_and_mt:  print(row)

# Find the critical path
critical_path = [task[0] for task in table_with_times_and_mt if task[-1] == 0 and task[0] != 'TASK']
print("Critical Path:", critical_path)
```

The critical path method is a project management tool, which is related to graph theory, so here I will attach a network or graph representative of this problem from which I try to make the table of times and total margin for each task of the project.

[image]